How to run functions on background thread in jetpack compose?
I'm encountering a scenario in my Android application where certain calculations occasionally result in a NumberFormatException. To handle this, I've implemented a Try Catch block, which effectively resolves the issue. However, this solution has led to another problem – ANR (Application Not Responding) due to UI blocking. After some investigation, I've learned that the Try Catch blocks are causing the UI to block, resulting in the ANR.
My question is: How can I utilize Try Catch on a separate background thread to prevent it from blocking the main UI? It's important to note that the functions within the Try Catch blocks are primarily used for mathematical computations. Below is a snippet of the relevant code from my original implementation:
First Example:
val areaInSqMeter: Double? = try {
    SphericalUtil.computeArea(geoPoints)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("MapScreen", "$e")
    null
}

areaInSqMeter?.let {
    // updating viemodel variables and showing data
}


To not block the UI, you can use Coroutines scope from your view model and specify the dispacther if need like this:
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val areaInSqMeter: Double? = try {
        SphericalUtil.computeArea(geoPoints)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("MapScreen", "$e")
        null
    }

    areaInSqMeter?.let {
        // updating viemodel variables and showing data
    }
}

You can also use withContext() instead of viewmodel scope like this:
withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {              
    
}  

Assuming your computation tasks are related to CPU intensive work, you can use Dispacthers.Default instead of IO since later it is used for network and read/write operations. You can learn more on this topic from the official documentation here: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv
And if you are in the UI want to await the result then you can pair it up with LaunchedEffect and provide appropriate key for recomposition. Here's an example from my code:
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    this.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
        try {
            extractVideoFrames(Constants.BASE_URL + clipInfo.videoURL, clipBuilderViewModel)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e("Extracting video frames failed with exception: ${e.message}")
        }
    }.await()
}

